# Getting Data In Random Order From Set Which Is Permanently Stored Using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save an ArrayList named "notes" using SharedPreferences and Set but when i retrieve this data i get this data in random order, I tried to figure out what's the problem but no luck.

```
sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.aadil.notes",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

    notes.clear()

    if (set != null) {
            notes.addAll(set);
        }
        else {
            notes.add("test data 1");
            notes.add("test data 2");

            set = new HashSet<String>();                    
            set.addAll(notes);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can never be sure in which order the elements are ordered inside a HashSet, to solve this problem you can use a LinkedHashSet in your Code:

```
set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

For Reference: [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)